# Merge two dataframes with overlapping index, keeping column values from left DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How can I join/merge two Pandas DataFrames with partially overlapping indexes, where I wish the resulting joined DataFrame to retain the column values in the first DataFrame i.e. dropping the duplicates in `df2`?

```
import pandas as pd
import io  
    
df1 = """
date; count
'2020-01-01'; 210
'2020-01-02'; 189
'2020-01-03'; 612
'2020-01-04'; 492
'2020-01-05'; 185
'2020-01-06'; 492
'2020-01-07'; 155
'2020-01-08'; 62
'2020-01-09'; 15
"""
df2 = """
date; count
'2020-01-04'; 21
'2020-01-05'; 516
'2020-01-06'; 121
'2020-01-07'; 116
'2020-01-08'; 82
'2020-01-09'; 121
'2020-01-10'; 116
'2020-01-11'; 82
'2020-01-12'; 116
'2020-01-13'; 82
"""


df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df1), sep=";")
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df2), sep=";")
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

I have tried using

```
df1.reset_index().merge(df2, how='outer').set_index('date')
```

however, this drops the joined df2 values. Is there a method to keep the duplicated rows of the first dataframe?

Desired outcome:

```
print(df3)
 date        count
'2020-01-01' 210
'2020-01-02' 189
'2020-01-03' 612
'2020-01-04' 492
'2020-01-05' 185
'2020-01-06' 492
'2020-01-07' 155
'2020-01-08' 62
'2020-01-09' 15
'2020-01-10' 116
'2020-01-11' 82
'2020-01-12' 116
'2020-01-13' 82
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `combine_first`:

```
df3 = (df1.set_index('date')
          .combine_first(df2.set_index('date'))
          .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
            date   count
0   '2020-01-01'     210
1   '2020-01-02'     189
2   '2020-01-03'     612
3   '2020-01-04'     492
4   '2020-01-05'     185
5   '2020-01-06'     492
6   '2020-01-07'     155
7   '2020-01-08'      62
8   '2020-01-09'      15
9   '2020-01-10'     116
10  '2020-01-11'      82
11  '2020-01-12'     116
12  '2020-01-13'      82
```

Comment: Thank you for this, very helpful. Unfortunately I got my dataframes mixed up - i want to keep the rows of the second dataframe (effectively preprend) so will ask in a separate Q.

Comment: @cmp you mean you want to give priority to the values of the second DF? Then just invert `df1` and `df2`

Comment: Yes that's right. I have tried this but the result still seems to retain the values from df1 where they overlap? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried and it works fine with the provided examples. Please double check carefully ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is another way using`concat` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df3=pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(["date"], keep="first", ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
            date   count
0   '2020-01-01'     210
1   '2020-01-02'     189
2   '2020-01-03'     612
3   '2020-01-04'     492
4   '2020-01-05'     185
5   '2020-01-06'     492
6   '2020-01-07'     155
7   '2020-01-08'      62
8   '2020-01-09'      15
9   '2020-01-10'     116
10  '2020-01-11'      82
11  '2020-01-12'     116
12  '2020-01-13'      82
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.merge(df2,on='date',how="outer",suffixes=[None,'_2']).bfill(axis=1).drop(" count_2",axis=1)
```

output:

```
            date   count
0   '2020-01-01'     210
1   '2020-01-02'     189
2   '2020-01-03'     612
3   '2020-01-04'     492
4   '2020-01-05'     185
5   '2020-01-06'     492
6   '2020-01-07'     155
7   '2020-01-08'      62
8   '2020-01-09'      15
9   '2020-01-10'     116
10  '2020-01-11'      82
11  '2020-01-12'     116
12  '2020-01-13'      82
```